# RequiredFieldValidator not working in my ASp site

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn some C# & asp, while creating a booking page in Visual Studio. I have faced a little problem with the RequiredFieldValidator, because when i click the button, nothing happens.

I'm using the bootstrap css files to make in a little more shiny. **Some code of the registrationpage is here:**

**Updated code**

```
<asp:Content ID="RegistrationContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<br />
<div class="container">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <p>Please fill out the forms to complete your registration.</p>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Name:</label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="Registration" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="Registration" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="An password is required." ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ValidationGroup="Registration" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="form-control" ValidationGroup="Registration" TextMode="Password" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="An password is required." ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" ValidationGroup="Registration" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" ValidationGroup="Registration" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Create</button>
            &nbsp;
            <button type="reset" ValidationGroup="Registration" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Have made the validationgroup, but it still does not work.. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just miss a little thing i.e. to assign a Validation Group to your buttons and your RequiredFieldValidators. Your code should be:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <p>Please fill out the forms to complete your registration.</p>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Name:</label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." ValidationGroup="Group1" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The email field is required." ValidationGroup="Group1" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="An password is required." ValidationGroup="Group1" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmpassword">Confirm Password:</label>
             <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="An password is required." ValidationGroup="Group1" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:button ValidationGroup="Group1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Create</asp:button>
            &nbsp;
            <asp:button ValidationGroup="Group1" type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset</asp:button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Still does not work.. i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.. without the earlier, when i followed an tutorial without bootstrap css, it worked.

Comment: Found the problem.. your code was right.. it was the button which caused the problem.